# Is it possible to show any part of the text in a select list in italics?

Tags: html, css

I have a standard kind of select list:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi cars</option>
</select>
```

Is it possible to display for example the word "cars" in italics? I tried adding standard html but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please Note : Checked Only On **Firefox 10.2** but it does accomplish
>   what has been asked here

I can use CSS to do it like this [**My Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ay8A/)

HTML

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option class="italic" value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

CSS

```
option.italic:after{
    content: "cars";
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: @any user who -1 this can I ask you why?

Comment: @prash I didn't pointed you out bro and you can see my fiddle

Comment: The question is asked that only word cars should be italics...`Is it possible to display for example the word "cars" in italics?`

Comment: i am sorry,but in my system ,your fiddle is not working,Pls check once more

Comment: @Jack I know i guess it needs doctype declaration to do it, right now it works on firefox

Answer (score 2):

No - as with input fields and text areas, option tags do not allow for differing styles within them, only one style for the entire option.

To achieve what you describe, you will need a HTML/JavaScript simulation of a dropdown, not a native one, e.g.

http://www.mitya.co.uk/scripts/jQuery-drop-down-selector-124

Answer (score 0):

it's pretty much impossible to do using straight html.

same style you can possible

```
SELECT { border: solid 1px color; font-weight: bold; }
OPTION { background:xx; font-style: italic; }
```

but for different style you should use javascript.